# How to process data in PHP that was serialized and sent from jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm struggling to get a $.ajax call to correctly send some form data to PHP (where it gets recorded to a database and then displayed). I'm stumped because I've $.ajax to do similar tasks before and it's worked great but I must be missing something critical here. I've researched other answers (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325867/jquery-process-form)) but can't find anything there that suggests my current code would not work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

The form looks like this:

```
            <div id="note_add_container">
                <form id="note_add" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title" />
                    <input type="text" name="summary" placeholder="summary" />
                    <input type="text" name="details" placeholder="details" />
                    <button id="submit_note">Add note!</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="entries">
                <!-- AJAX call will populate entries here -->
            </div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
    $('#submit_note').click(function () {
        var text = $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "note_process.php",
            data: $('#note_add').serialize(), 
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
        }).responseText;
        $('#entries').html(text); 
    })
```

Here is the PHP note_process.php:

```
include_once "connect.php";
session_start();

$id = $_SESSION['userid'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$summary = $_POST['summary'];
$details = $_POST['details'];

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notes (id, title, summary, details) VALUES ('$id', '$title','$summary','$details')");

echo $title . $summary . $details;
```

Comment: Could you explain **what** doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clear on that. The part that is not working is that the line that should be echo'd from the PHP does not populate within the DIV "entries" as intended.

Comment: I guess the post vars are serialized. You need to json_decode it first.

Comment: use firebug, check the console to see if the data are being posted correctly, also, check the response if any.

Comment: mixdev - sorry I'm new to this but if I decoded using json_decode($somedata) how do I pass the data from the form into $somedata?

Comment: Add a semicolon ';' to your closing bracket })    like so:   });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'success', instead of making the Ajax request not-async...

```
   $('#submit_note').click(function () {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "note_process.php",
            data: $('#note_add').serialize(), 
            success: function(text){
                  $('#entries').html(text); 
            }
        });    
    });
```

Comment: This code seems to be right, are you receiving something from the server?

Comment: I don't think I'm getting anything back from the server, even if I just put a echo 'hello world' line in the PHP i don't get that back

Comment: Jordan - Thanks! I just tried this code again and realized I'd copied it before you made the edit and thats why it wasn't working. Thanks to everyone to helped. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sync should still work though... There's absolutely no reason async would work and sync wouldn't...

Answer (score 0):

If things still aren't working, I'd be weary of whether your url is accurate...
Try using an absolute path to your PHP file instead... such as "/note_process.php" (or wherever the file is located relative to your site root)

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess:

1. You have error reporting turned off (bad while in dev phase)
2. `title` column is `required` in your `notes` table,
3. (this is a fact) you are using the wrong post parameter in `$title = $_POST['type'];`

So:

1. `$title = $_POST['type'];` should generate a warning, but it doesn't,
2. `$title` will be blank and your query fails to insert the record and you get a fatal error, but do not see it.

Comment: Thanks for catching 3 - that is definitely true. I fixed that and am still running into issues though. I found that if I use this code (below) I can get echo 'hello world' from the server but I still can't echo anything from the form.      $('#submit_note').click(function (){
        $('#entries').append( $('<div>').load('note_process.php', $('#note_add').serialize() ));
        return false;
    })

Comment: I suggest you construct the query and assign it to a string: `$query = "INSERT INTO notes ...";`, then `die($query)`, and then catch it in firbug and test it in PHPMyAdmin to see what you get.

Answer (score -1):

My findings on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/6XZP8/): the `<button>` seems to be submitting the form!? God knows why!? The solution is fairly simple =) Don't use a `<button>`

Replace the BUTTON tag with an A tag and it works fine.

Jordan Rynard has good point: you sure your URL is valid and correct?

Comment: Hmmm. I replaced the button and still no luck. I have verified that the URL is valid (see the comment on the answer above) because I got the server to return a hard-coded echo but I'm still getting this "undefined index" error for all the form data I try to retrieve using $_POST

Comment: That's an error from your MySQL database... (undefined index)

Comment: I think it's an error I'm getting because it can't find $_POST['title'], $_POST['summary'] and $_POST['details']. The error references those 3 lines and I still get it even if I comment out the mysql query.

Comment: It's not a database error. "undefined index" is exactly what john k says: a 'missing' element in a php array. **edit** So it looks like the data is not sent and/or received correctly...